# Is it possible to have auto suggestion of schema names?

Tags: autocompletion

(tag suggestions welcome)

I've just started learning Vim.

My other text editor, which I use for writing Hive queries is a browser based editor which has this very useful feature of auto suggesting schema and table names as a drop down as I start typing.

e.g.
[image]

This is handy since other schema names and table names are long and or have nuances around underscrores or dashes which I often forget.

I guess it's probably a long shot but I wanted to ask anyway. Is there some way for me to pass vim the schemas and store them somewhere so that vim could auto suggest as I type like in the screen shot?

Comment: One could create a custom completion function and use it via omni or user completion. Implementation would require a lot more detail to your question.